Expressing the zeta function as a sum of primes
We begin with the well-known Euler product form of the Riemann zeta function, an alternative to the summation definition. We can then expand it into a series:
$$ \zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_{p} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} = \prod_{p} 1+ \frac{1}{p^s-1} = \biggl(1+\frac{1}{p_{1}^s-1}\biggl)\biggl(1+\frac{1}{p_{2}^s-1}\biggl)\dots\biggl(1+\frac{1}{p_{n}^s-1}\biggl) $$
At this point we can substitute $a_n$ with $p_{n}^s-1$, simplifying the notation:
$$ p_{n}^s-1 = a_n \to \biggl(1+\frac{1}{a_1}\biggl)\biggl(1+\frac{1}{a_2}\biggl)\biggl(1+\frac{1}{a_3}\biggl)\biggl(1+\frac{1}{a_4}\biggl)\dots\biggl(1+\frac{1}{a_n}\biggl) = $$
$$ = \biggl[1+\biggl(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3}+\frac{1}{a_4}+\dots\biggl)+\biggl(\frac{1}{a_1a_2}+\frac{1}{a_1a_3}+\frac{1}{a_2a_3}+\frac{1}{a_2a_4}+\frac{1}{a_3a_4}+\frac{1}{a_1a_4}+\dots\biggl)+ $$
$$\biggl(\frac{1}{a_1a_2a_3}+\frac{1}{a_1a_2a_4}+\frac{1}{a_1a_3a_4}+\frac{1}{a_2a_3a_4}+\dots\biggl) + \biggl(\frac{1}{a_1a_2a_3a_4}\biggl)\biggl]\biggl(1+\frac{1}{a_n}\biggl)  $$ \
Writing each level of expansion as a sum allows us to use notation that expresses the increasing number of factors in each term. The first sum is simply:
$$ \biggl(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3}+\frac{1}{a_4}+\dots\biggl) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_i} $$
This is a simple sum of inverses. However the following series will need a representation that takes into count the permutations of indexes, so we'll have, starting from one element, ($a_i$) up to three ($a_ia_ja_k)$:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_i} \rightarrow \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n} \frac{1}{a_ia_j} \rightarrow \sum_{1\leq i<j<k\leq n} \frac{1}{a_ia_ja_k} $$
\justifying{This pattern continues, with each term represented as a sum of all products of $k$ distinct terms. For example, with $n=4$, taking terms where $1\leq i<j\leq 4$ yields six possible pairs. This happens because the number of permutations can be calculated using the binomial coefficient $ \binom{n}{k} $ where n is the number of terms chosen and k is the number of elements (for n=4 of k=2 the binomial coefficient is $\binom{4}{2} = 6$).}
In general, the form of each term can be expressed as:
$$ \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k \leq n} \frac{1}{a_{i_1} a_{i_2} \cdots a_{i_k}}$$
Thus, we can express the sum as:
$$ 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n} \biggl(\sum_{1 \leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq n} \frac{1}{a_{i_1}  \cdots a_{i_k}}\biggl)+\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n}$$
The product term tends to zero as $n\to\infty$, shown as follows:
$$ \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{p_{n}^s-1} = \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\exp\biggl[\biggl(-\sum_{n=1}^{k} \ln\biggl(\frac{1}{p_{n}^s-1}\biggl)\biggl] = \lim\limits_{k\to\infty} e^{-k} = 0$$
This follows because the sequence diverges as $k\to\infty$, leading the exponential term to tend to zero.
With the product term being simplified, we are left with the following identity:
$$ \zeta(s) = 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq n} \frac{1}{a_{i_1}  \cdots a_{i_k}}$$
Subbing in $p^s_{n}-1 = a_n$ and applying the limit to infinity for accuracy:
$$ \zeta(s) = 1+\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq n} \frac{1}{(p^s_{i_1}-1)  \cdots (p^s_{i_k}-1)}$$
Are there any mistakes or typos in this demonstration?

“For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.”

Your final formula doesn't look right since it implies you can express $\zeta(s)$ as a finite sum which would be rational, and note that $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ for example is irrational. Perhaps you meant $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$?

@StevenClark yep i should have put that lim, since the result is more accurate the more the terms
